# How to edit a cursor attribute for a return statement on plsql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I want to return a cursor from a function, I have read that I can use:

```
return sys_refcursor
```

And then

```
open curs for select* from mytable;
return curs;
```

I tried curs.att := 'something' but I get an error

Also read I can do my own type:

```
 TYPE type IS REF CURSOR RETURN mytable%ROWTYPE;
```

Then

```
CURSOR cur IS
    SELECT* FROM mytable;
var cur%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
OPEN cur;
FETCH cur INTO var;
var.att = 'something';
RETURN var;
```

This time I didn't get an error in the assign but in the return statement.

If I changed the var type to my type I couldn't fetch the value.

I wan't to edit the cursor, but not the table, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cursor is a read-only structure.  The only way to change the data that you would fetch from a cursor is to change the SQL statement that is used to open the cursor or to change the data in the underlying table(s).

While it is possible to return a cursor from one PL/SQL block to another, it is rarely the appropriate architecture.  A `SYS_REFCURSOR` is generally appropriate when you want to return a result to a client application that knows how to use a cursor.

Do you really want to return a cursor, though?  Or do you want to return a record type?  The second code snippet you posted appears to be trying to return a record-- that's certainly possible but you would need to declare that the function returns a record rather than a cursor.  That is, the `RETURN` statement in the declaration would need to be `RETURN mytable%ROWTYPE` rather than `RETURN type`.  For example, if you want to return a record based on the `EMP` table

```
create or replace function get_emp( p_empno in emp.empno%type )
  return emp%rowtype
is
  l_rec emp%rowtype;
begin
  select *
    into l_rec
    from emp
   where empno = p_empno;
  l_rec.sal := l_rec.sal + 100;
  return l_rec;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using just a record but when I add the RETURN mytable%ROWTYPE I get this error: 
Compilation failed,line 1 (20:24:56) PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformedCompilation failed

Comment: @Warner - I posted an example using the `EMP` table.  If you are still getting an error, please post the code that you're using.

Comment: Nevermind, I just added the schema to it schem.mytable, it's weird though.
Doing it like that worked, and about the edition of the record I think I'm misleading the function of procedures, I will work with it at the application code.
Thanks

Comment: Ahh but I can change implicit cursors then, I'm still not sure if I should do it at the data base or at the application. It's a mp3 store, if the person clicks a song it will play part of the song but if the person buys it, it will play the full song.
In the returned record I was thinkin to hide the full song to the people that haven't buy it.

Comment: @Warer - You can't change the data in a cursor whether it is an explicit or an implicit cursor.  You can change the data in a record whether that record is populated from an explicit cursor, an implicit cursor, or manually.